# Can't connect to Mysql server via Python (Error 111)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I've recently started learning python and coming from PHP I thought a great way to do so would be transforming php scripts into python. I started with the basics: dates, lists, arrays, functions... so I went to try basic mysql connection.

The issue came here, as every time I execute the script an exception is returned stating:

> 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xxx.x' (111)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "connections/connection.py", line 23, in 
> accountingCursor = accountingDb.cursor()
> NameError: name 'accountingDb' is not defined

The funny thing is that the same connection seems to be working just fine when attemped from the php script. I don't really know what am I missing, but I've been following the official documentation from [MySQL webpage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) and still no clue as to what could be wrong.

This is my attempt:

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


try:
    accountingDb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="xx.xxx.xxx.x",
        database="dbname",
        user="user",
        password="pswrd"
    )
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Error en usuario o contraseña")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("No existe la Base de Datos")
    else:
        print(err)


accountingCursor = accountingDb.cursor()
```

Comment: are you using "xx.xxx.xxx.x" as your ip?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JamM.HernandezQuiceno. I wrote it that way out of paranoia, but it is a real address I am trying to connect to. Neither it is localhost, as I've seen quite a few related questions but were all about connecting to localhost and managing apache config files. In my case, access to the server works just great, I can access the db using  the console and the original `PHP` file I 'converted' to `python` also connects fine. But whenever I try using the new script I stumble upon the same error warning.

Answer (score 1):

write localhost as the host and then try.
Something like this

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="pass")
print(mydb)
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
```